# Grails: how to define a master-detail view with grails constraints

Tags: java, grails, grails-orm

I want to create a simple master/detail view with these tables:

```
create table MASTER_ID2
(
   ID                   int not null,
   VALOR                varchar(40),
   primary key (ID)
);

create table DETAIL_ID2
 (
   ID                   int not null,
   ID_MASTER            int not null,
   VALOR_DET            char(40),
   primary key (ID)
);

alter table DETAIL_ID2 add constraint FK_RDET5 foreign key (ID_MASTER)
      references MASTER_ID2 (ID) on delete restrict on update restrict;
```

I have these domain classes:

```
class MasterId2 {

    Integer id
    String valor
    //
    static hasMany = [details : DetailId2]

    static mapping = {
        table 'master_id2'
        version false
        id generator:'identity', column:'ID'
        //
        details column: 'id_master'     
    }

    static constraints = {
        id(max: 2147483647)
        valor(size: 0..40)
    }

    String toString() {
        return "${id}" 
    }
}

class DetailId2  implements Serializable {

    Integer id
    Integer id_master
    String valor_det
    //
    MasterId2 master
    static belongsTo = MasterId2

    static mapping = {
        table 'detail_id2'
        version false
        id generator:'identity', column:'ID'
    }

    static constraints = {
        id(max: 2147483647)
        valor_det(size: 0..40)
    }

    String toString() {
        return "${id}" 
    }
}
```

But the detail view doesn't  assign a foreign key.

What is wrong in my code?

---

i make this changes

class MasterId2 {

```
Integer id
String valor
//
static hasMany = [details : DetailId2]

static mapping = {
    table 'master_id2'
    // version is set to false, because this isn't available by default for legacy databases
    version false
    id generator:'identity', column:'ID'
    //
    details column: 'id_master'
```

}

```
static constraints = {
    id(max: 2147483647)
    valor(size: 0..40)
}
String toString() {
    return "${id}" 
}
```

}

class DetailId2  implements Serializable {

```
Integer id
Integer id_master
String valor_det
//
//MasterId2 master
//static belongsTo = MasterId2
static belongsTo = [master: MasterId2]

static mapping = {
    table 'detail_id2'
    // version is set to false, because this isn't available by default for legacy databases
    version false
    id generator:'identity', column:'ID'
    //
    master insertable: false               // enforce foreign key
    master updateable: false               // enforce foreign key
```

}

```
static constraints = {
    id(max: 2147483647)
    valor_det(size: 0..40)
}
String toString() {
    return "${id}" 
}
```

}

but i get this form

Valordet    -> edit

Idmaster *  -> edit

**Master *    -> listbox without values**

any idea?

Comment: Are you trying to map to existing schema or are you letting Grails create the schema for you?

Answer (score 0):

Change the mapping of DetailId2 from

```
static mapping = {
        table 'detail_id2'
        version false
        id generator:'identity', column:'ID'
    }
```

to

```
static mapping = {
        table 'detail_id2'
        version false
        id generator:'identity', column:'ID'
        master insertable: false               // enforce foreign key
        master updateable: false               // enforce foreign key
    }
```

Comment: I redefine the detail lass in this way